# What is wrong with the output to the screen?

Tags: c++

The code works fine, it's running and everything;

```
printf("\nEnter number of hours ");
scanf("%f", &hours);

{
    if (hours>=5) {
        calc_charge=minimum_fee;
        bill = hours * minimum_fee;
        printf("%i", &bill);
    }
    else
        if(hours>=8) {
            bill=hours*mini_fee;
            printf("%i", &bill);
        }
        else
            if (hours <= 24) {
                bill = hours*maximum_fee;
                printf("%i", &bill);
            }

    while (hours >= 4) {
        bill = hours*minimum_fee;
        printf("%i", &bill);
    }
```

But the output is

> 34525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160134525160

I can't seem to find anything wrong, the code is just not doing the calculations. Why not?

Comment: Make it a habit to format your code before posting here and to give us minimally complete or better compilable code. We don't know the type of `hours` and therefore we don't know if `"%f"` is the correct type specifier.

Comment: The following part doesn't make sense: `if (hours>=5) {...} else if(hours>=8) {...}` - your conditions inside `if` seem wrong

Answer (score 12):

Remove `&` at all of your printfs. You want to  print the value of the variable not its address.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to removing the `&` as suggested by Armin, it might also help to add newlines `\n`s or at least spaces to your printfs, e.g.:

```
printf("%i\n", bill);
```

Otherwise your numbers are printed right next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

There is an infinite loop in your code:

```
while (hours >= 4) {
    bill = hours*minimum_fee;
    printf("%i", &bill);
}
```

Maybe you want to print only once:

```
    bill = hours*minimum_fee;
    printf("%i", &bill);
```

Or maybe you wanted to write `if` instead of `while`? (just a guess, not a suggestion)